# Run a functions across pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I try to make a function running across pages.

The function likes below:

1. open a web and wait till document.readyState is "complete".
2. do something in the opened page.
3. get&click submit button.
4. wait till page is loaded and get&click submit button again.

step 1 and 2 is in a same page, step 3 and 4 is different.

What I want to know is whether it is possible to run such functions on chrome Javascript console or not.
And is there any other way to realize it?

Comment: In the console? So you're making some kind of macro?

Comment: yes. It likes a kind of macro. But I have no idea that what kind of platform is suitable for my scenario.

Comment: Have a look at http://seleniumhq.org/ this might be what you want

Comment: Sounds like you can (also) use chrome extensions in order to do it...